# error trying to redirect output of awk script to a new file

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk

I am working on the following code in an awk script and I need the output to be redirected to another file within the same script.

What I try to do in the first block is to round the decimals of the numbers in column 9, and in the second I want to create a new column from calculating a percentage. The output is correct but at the end I want to send all the lines to a file.

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {print; next}
{ $8 = sprintf("%0.4f", $8) }
{ a[$0]++ }


BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
{ gsub(/\r/,"") }
FNR==1 { $10="Column"  }
FNR > 1 && ($12+0==$12 && $16+0==$16 && $13+0==$13){
  $10=sprintf("%0.4f",(($15-$16)/$13)*100)
}1

END {
  if (i>0){
    for  (i in a){
        print "i" > nj.csv
}}}
```

This is my code and just by executing it I get an error pointing to the point between nj and csv (nj.csv). Any idea to solve it?

Comment: `nj.csv` is the variables `nj` and `csv` with a dot as an operator or something between them, but I don't recall such an operator. I suppose you meant `"nj.csv"`

Comment: @muru If I do it that way and then I run cat nj.csv I get No such file or directory

Comment: And you don't see anything related in, e.g. the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: I've checked and no

Comment: In that case your input never resulted in `i > 0` or a nonempty `a`, I'd guess. I can't even tell where `i` is being set in that other than in the loop, but that's too late for the outer `i > 0` check

Comment: I also suspect that the third block does not do what it is supposed to do, which is to check line by line and pass it to the nj.csv file.Could you please suggest some way to do it?

Comment: @oshiono if you want additional help, please [edit] your question to explain what your script is *intended* to do, preferably with a minimal sample of input and expected output.

Comment: @steeldriver Done! Hope this helps

Comment: What about the corresponding input? Are you also attempting to de-duplicate records? If not, I don't see the need for the `{a[$0]++}` block or the `END` block. In fact there's a lot that doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: Well the first two BEGIN blocks return me what I need, the only thing is that I don't know how to make so that inside the same script each one of the lines is sent to another file, simply that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be stream-processing records, and redirecting the result to a single file with fixed name. So there's no need to store anything (`a[$0]++`) nor to loop over anything at the `END`, nor to do the redirection inside awk (you can simply shell-redirect the output of the whole command).

My best guess of what you are trying to do is:

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
  NR == 1 {$10 = "Survival Percentage"} 
  NR > 1 {
    $9 = sprintf("%0.2f",$9)
    $10 = ($5+0==$5 && $6+0==$6 && $3+0==$3) ? sprintf("%0.2f",(($5-$6)/$3)*100) : "N/A"
  } 
  {print}
' input.csv > nj.csv
```

I removed the `gsub(/\r/,"")` in favour of setting the input record separator to handle an optional CR. This is really equivalent to `sub(/\r$/,"")` - I'm assuming that you don't really need to handle CR characters except at the EOL.

---

To make it into a script:

```
BEGIN{RS = "\r?\n"; FS = ","; OFS = FS}
  NR == 1 {$10 = "Survival Percentage"}
  NR > 1 {
    $9 = sprintf("%0.2f",$9)
    $10 = ($5+0==$5 && $6+0==$6 && $3+0==$3) ? sprintf("%0.2f",(($5-$6)/$3)*100) : "N/A"
  }
  {print}
```

and then execute with **redirection handled by your shell** as

```
awk -f awk_script.awk dataset.csv > nj.csv
```

**or** make it an [executable awk script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Executable-Scripts):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{RS = "\r?\n"; FS = ","; OFS = FS}
  NR == 1 {$10 = "Survival Percentage"}
  NR > 1 {
    $9 = sprintf("%0.2f",$9)
    $10 = ($5+0==$5 && $6+0==$6 && $3+0==$3) ? sprintf("%0.2f",(($5-$6)/$3)*100) : "N/A"
  }
  {print}
```

make it executable, then run as

```
./awk_script.awk dataset.csv > nj.csv
```

If you *insist* on placing the output **redirection inside awk** then it needs to be written as `{print > "nj.csv"}`.

Comment: Hi @steeldriver I need to run the script like this gawk -f awk_script.awk dataset.csv . I don't think it would work like that, would it?

Comment: @oshiono you will need to move the field and record separator assignments into the `BEGIN` block i.e. `BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"; FS=","; OFS = FS}`

Comment: I tried to use your code (see edit) and it returns syntax error here ">"

Comment: @oshiono that's because you are mixing up shell redirection and awk redirection - see edit

Comment: Hi @steeldriver your code works perfectly. Finally, do you think there is any way that within the same code that you have proposed to me there is an explicit for or while to redirect to nj.csv the records that do not have any N/A (maybe in the end block). I would appreciate it very much